Maror - bitter or sweet?
The Gemara (Pesachim 115b) says that if one swallowed the Maror, he is not Yotze, being that one must taste the bitterness.
Question: it says in the Yerushalmi (Pesachim 2:5) that Chazeret is originally sweet - how is this allowed if one must taste the bitterness?!

Seemingly whatever the flavor is it what you must taste

The same gemara in Pesachim says that you should not dip the marror into too much charoses because it will take away the bitterness.

This seems to be subject to a machlokes.
The Mishna Berura 475:30 (quoting the Magen Avraham) says that there’s a requirement to taste a bitterness:

דטעם מרור בעינן - שירגיש המרירות בפיו זכר לוימררו את חייהם

The Chaya Adam 130:3 says clearly that no bitter taste is required:

ואע"ג דאינו מר כלל לא אכפת לן (וז"ל אורח חיים ולא צריך למהדר אמרריתא דהא מצוה בחזרת ומאי חסא דחס כו' ובירושלמי התיבון הרי חזרת אינו קרוי מרור אלא מתוק רבי חייא בר הושעיה כל עצמו אינו תלוי אלא בחזרת)

R’ Nissim Karelitz in Chut Shani Perek 17, footnote 15 at the end, says that the Chazon Ish made sure to use the younger not ripened leaves, so that it had a bitterness.
The Shulchan Aruch Harav 472:30 agrees with the Chaya Adam and says sweet tasting romaine is good as well

וְאַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהַחֲזֶרֶת אֵין בָּהּ מְרִירוּת, מִכָּל מָקוֹם כְּשֶׁהִיא שׁוֹהָה בַּקַּרְקַע מִתְקַשֶּׁה הַקֶּלַח שֶׁלָּהּ וְנַעֲשֶׂה מַר מְאֹד, וּמִפְּנֵי כָּךְ הִיא נִקְרֵאת מָרוֹר.
וּמִצְוָה לַחֲזֹר אַחֲרֶיהָ אַף כְּשֶׁהִיא מְתוּקָה, לְפִי שֶׁמִּצְוַת מָרוֹר הִיא זֵכֶר לְמַה שֶּׁמֵּרְרוּ הַמִּצְרִים אֶת חַיֵּי אֲבוֹתֵינוּ בַּעֲבוֹדַת פֶּרֶךְ, וְהֵם נִשְׁתַּעְבְּדוּ בָּהֶם בִּתְחִלָּה בְּפֶה רַךְ עַל יְדֵי פִּיּוּסִים, וְנָתְנוּ לָהֶם שָׂכָר, וּלְבַסּוֹף מֵרְרוּ חַיֵּיהֶם בַּעֲבוֹדָה קָשָׁה, לָכֵן יֵשׁ לֶאֱכֹל הַחֲזֶרֶת שֶׁתְּחִלָּתָהּ מְתוּקָה וְרַכָּה וְסוֹפָהּ קָשֶׁה וָמַר, דְּהַיְנוּ כְּשֶׁהַקֶּלַח שֶׁלָּהּ מִתְקַשֶּׁה כְּעֵץ וְנַעֲשֶׂה מַר כַּלַּעֲנָה

R’ Shlomo Zalman in Halichos Shlomo Pesach 21:7 explains that those who say you don’t need to taste bitterness, understand the meaning of “to have the bitter taste in your mouth” to refer to the taste of the lettuce, not necessarily the bitter taste (the taste of the marror, whatever that is, not necessarily bitter per se).
